# Import a pdf or word document to crystal reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2010

Actually I am new to crystal reports in C#. I have around 10 Word documents and 5 PDF documents. My question is there any way to put each document directly to crystal reports and edit it without the need to design each document from the scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps to import a Microsoft Word document (*.doc) into a report using Crystal Reports:

1) Create a new Crystal report.

2) From the Insert menu, click OLE object.

3) Select Create from file.

4) Click Browse and open the file to use (in this case the Word document).

5) Place the OLE object in the section where you would like to see it.

You can only place the OLE Object in one section. You may need to create a Word document for each section. For instance, you can create a word document to use as OLE object in the Report Header section, and another one to place in the Page Header

Comment: I have applied what you said but is this way will allow me to bind different parts of the document from the database?

Comment: You might be able to embed the Word doc as a background and then create formula fields that are placed so they print over the embedded Word doc, but I wouldn't recommend this approach as it will be painfully difficult to make the document look seamless and professional.  You would be far better served to simply use Crystal Report to recreate the layout of the Word doc.

Comment: It also may help to note that you might be able to achieve your goal using only Word and moving away from Crystal Reports altogether if you setup your Word Document as a Merge Document.

Comment: Merge Document.

Comment: reate a Typed DataSet from the "Add New Item > DataSet and give the dataset a useful name.

In Server Explorer, drag a view with the fields you want in the report onto the dataSet.


In the 'Data' tab, click the node for "More Data Sources"

Click the node for ADO .Net (XML)

Check the box for 'Use Visual Studio Data Class'

In the 'Visual Studio Data Class name' combobox, select the name of the dataset you just created.

click 'Finish'

Choose the table displaying under the name of the dataset you just added to the 'Data' tab and click 'Insert Table'

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to convert the PDF into an image then place each page on design area...